# Disabling HTML Escaping in Magento Backend

Tags: backend

I'm using some Magento module and the option title is in HTML. I upgraded from Magento 2.2.3 to 2.2.10 and they obviously introduced escaping here, which wasn't there before.

Is there a way to stop this behavior in the backend?
Way to disable XSS protection in the backend?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution might be to create a preference and overwrite the file via DI.